# How can I limit fields in ToManyField with full=True in django-tastypie

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I have the following resource:

```
class MachineResource(ModelResource):
manager = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'manager',full=True)
class Meta:
    queryset = Service.objects.filter(service_type='machine')
    resource_name = 'machine'
```

This works fine. And will return a list of machines, and an embedded user object (the manager) in each.

However, I only one want 2-3 fields from the manager user. I dont want it to contain the managers salted pass and other private data for example.

As far as I can see there isn't a way I can do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally find the notion of creating two `ModelResource`s for the same Model class a bit inelegant. For instance, suppose you wanted to display the email field in the detail view of `UserResource` but not while being displayed as a full object as part of the `MachineResource`. The way I would solve your problem is by deleting the non-required field's key in the data dictionary of the embedded object in the `dehydrate` method. A bit hacky way maybe, but works fine for me. For your case, you can do:

```
class MachineResource(ModelResource):
    manager = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'manager',full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Service.objects.filter(service_type='machine')
        resource_name = 'machine'

    def dehydrate(self,bundle):
        del bundle.data['manager'].data['email']
        return bundle
```

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look at the [Quick Start section for django-tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#quick-start). There's a perfect example right there. When you define your `ModelResource` subclass for `User` (your "manager"), simply add a `Meta` class with an `exclude` attribute set to the list of fields you don't want to show.

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'auth/user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_superuser']
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. It does mean though that I will need to create a separate UserResource especially for embedding into the MachineResource (I have a standard UserResource class already for general use that excludes different fields to what I want excluding in the MachineResource class).

Comment: This is something I would prefer to avoid as I don't want a redundant variant of UserResource that is accessible by some URL. I suppose I could somehow remove its URL...?

Comment: `Resource`s don't automatically get URLs. You have to hook them up in your `urls.py`. Especially if you're doing `full=True`, it doesn't even need it's own URL.

Comment: Ah. I was originally under the impressions resources wouldn't work unless registered in urls.py. This was quite a silly thing to believe now I think about it. Thanks, you've been a great help :).